# Seagate ST4000DM000 4TB drive shows up as 2TB even after converting to gpt

Tags: hard-drive, diskpart

I am on a windows 11 laptop with this hard drive connected via SATA docking station to USB.
These drives (I have two) used to show up as 4TB on the same hardware.

I have run diskpart and run:

```
list disk
select disk 1
clean
convert gpt
create partition primary
format fs=ntfs quick
exit
```

I have tried changing to GPT with EaseUS

It always comes up as a 2TB drive.

I have verified it is a 4TB drive with CrystalDiskInfo

Any help will save the remaining hairs on my head!

Comment: wow - tough crowd.  I got negative points with no comment :-(

Comment: Could you check the partition manager and confirm that all of the HDDs space is in use by a partition?

Comment: I checked the partition manager.  All of the space is in a Healthy Basic Data Partition

Comment: I could imagine the SATA controller in your dock only being able to handle a max of 2TB. Could you try a different docking station or connect the drive to the internal SATA of a deskop to confirm my suspicion?

Answer (score 0):

So, my diskpart commands worked as described. It didn't show up correctly until I disconnected the drive and rebooted (?!)

This was completely repeatable and works perfectly

Comment: Hello! Did you manage to get this to work? I am having exactly the same problem.